# Custom parser for google protobuf

Tags: python, performance, formatting

I have written a module for parsing a format used by the [Defold](http://www.defold.com) game engine, it is essentially the google protobuf format, but with a lot of custom things to support how they handle internal things.

I would like to have the whole code reviewed, but seeing that it is fairly big (800 lines) I assume that is a no go? If someone could give it a quick read through that would be great, if not maybe only the actual parsing?

The code takes a document and then makes it into a "tree", with Elements and Attributes, you can then change the values and write it down again.

I have been writing python for years but I am all self taught and have never had something code reviewed, so I imagine I have a lot to learn.

The data that is read looks like this

```
name: "default"
scale_along_z: 0
embedded_instances {
  id: "go"
  data: "components {\n"
  "  id: \"script\"\n"
  "  component: \"/main/main.script\"\n"
  "  position {\n"
  "    x: 0.0\n"
  "    y: 0.0\n"
  "    z: 0.0\n"
  "  }\n"
  "  rotation {\n"
  "    x: 0.0\n"
  "    y: 0.0\n"
  "    z: 0.0\n"
  "    w: 1.0\n"
  "  }\n"
  "}\n"
  "components {\n"
  "  id: \"mockup\"\n"
  "  component: \"/main/mockup.gui\"\n"
  "  position {\n"
  "    x: 0.0\n"
  "    y: 0.0\n"
  "    z: 0.0\n"
  "  }\n"
  "  rotation {\n"
  "    x: 0.0\n"
  "    y: 0.0\n"
  "    z: 0.0\n"
  "    w: 1.0\n"
  "  }\n"
  "}\n"
  ""
  position {
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  }
  rotation {
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
  }
  scale3 {
    x: 1.0
    y: 1.0
    z: 1.0
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the code for this is huge and maybe too unreadable? The whole code is on github [https://github.com/Jerakin/DefTree/blob/master/deftree/**init**.py](https://github.com/Jerakin/DefTree/blob/master/deftree/__init__.py)

```
class BaseDefParser:  # pragma: no cover
    _pattern = ''
    _regex = re_compile(_pattern)
    file_path = None

    def __init__(self, root_element):
        self.root = root_element
        self._element_chain = [self.root]

    def _raise_parse_error(self):
        if self.file_path:
            raise ParseError("Error when parsing file: {}".format(self.file_path))
        raise ParseError("Error when parsing supplied document")

    def parse(self, source) -> 'DefTree':
        """Loads an external Defold section into this DefTree

        :param source: path to the file.
        :returns Element: root Element"""
        self.file_path = source
        document = self._open(self.file_path)
        return self._parse(document)

    def from_string(self, source) -> 'DefTree':
        """Parses an Defold section from a string constant

        :param source: string to parse.
        :returns Element: root Element"""

        return self._parse(source)

    def _parse(self, input_doc):
        document = input_doc
        last_index = True
        while last_index:
            last_index = self._tree_builder(document)
            if last_index:
                document = document[last_index:]
        return self.root

    def _tree_builder(self, document):
        """Searches the document for a match and builds the tree"""
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def _get_level(child):
        element_level = -1

        def _count_up(_child, count):
            parent = _child.get_parent()
            if not parent:
                return count

            return _count_up(parent, count+1)
        return _count_up(child, element_level)

    @staticmethod
    def _open(_path):
        """Returns the documents data as a string"""

        with open(_path, "r") as document:
            current_document = document.read()
        return current_document

    @classmethod
    def serialize(cls, element) -> str:
        """Returns a string of the element"""
        return ""


class DefParser(BaseDefParser):
    _pattern = r'(?:data:)|(?:^|\s)(\w+):\s+(.+(?:\s+".*)*)|(\w*)\W{|(})'
    _regex = re_compile(_pattern)

    def __init__(self, root_element):
        super().__init__(root_element)

    def _tree_builder(self, document):
        """Searches the document for a match and builds the tree"""
        regex_match = self._regex.search(document)
        if not regex_match and len(document) > 25:
            self._raise_parse_error()
        if regex_match:
            element_name = regex_match.group(3)
            attribute_name, attribute_value = regex_match.group(1, 2)
            element_exit = regex_match.group(4)

            if element_name:
                if self._element_chain:
                    last_element = self._element_chain[-1]
                else:
                    self._raise_parse_error()  # pragma: no cover
                element = last_element.add_element(element_name)
                self._element_chain.append(element)
            elif attribute_name and attribute_value:
                if attribute_name == "data":
                    attribute_value = bytes(attribute_value, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape").replace('\n"\n  "',
                                                                                                       "\n")[1:-1]
                    last_element = self._element_chain[-1]
                    element = last_element.add_element("data")
                    self._element_chain.append(element)
                    self._parse(attribute_value)
                    self._element_chain.pop()
                else:
                    if self._element_chain:
                        last_element = self._element_chain[-1]
                    else:
                        self._raise_parse_error()  # pragma: no cover
                    last_element.add_attribute(attribute_name, attribute_value)

            elif element_exit:
                if self._element_chain:
                    self._element_chain.pop()
                else:
                    self._raise_parse_error()  # pragma: no cover

            return regex_match.end()
        return False

    @classmethod
    def serialize(cls, element, internal=False):
        """Returns a string of the element"""
        assert_is_element(element)

        def construct_string(node):
            """Recursive function that formats the text"""
            nonlocal output_string
            nonlocal level
            for child in node:
                element_level = cls._get_level(child)
                if is_element(child):
                    if child.name == "data" and not internal:
                        value = cls._escape_element(child)
                        output_string += "{}{}: {}\n".format("  " * element_level, child.name, value)
                    else:
                        level += 1
                        output_string += "{}{} {{\n".format("  " * element_level, child.name)
                        construct_string(child)
                elif is_attribute(child):
                    output_string += "{}{}: {}\n".format("  " * element_level, child.name,
                                                         child.string)
                if level > element_level and not child.name == "data":
                    level -= 1
                    output_string += "{}{}".format("  " * level, "}\n")

        level = 0
        output_string = ""
        construct_string(element)
        return output_string

    @classmethod
    def _escape_element(cls, ele):
        def yield_attributes(element_parent):
            for child in element_parent:
                if is_attribute(child):
                    yield child
                else:
                    yield from yield_attributes(child)
        data_elements = dict()
        data_elements[cls._get_level(ele)] = [ele]

        for x in ele.iter_elements():
            if is_element(x) and x.name == "data":
                lvl = cls._get_level(x)
                if lvl not in data_elements:
                    data_elements[lvl] = []
                data_elements[lvl].append(x)

        while data_elements:
            for x in data_elements[max(data_elements)]:
                for a in yield_attributes(x):
                    if isinstance(a, DefTreeString) and a.string.startswith('"') and a.string.endswith('"'):
                        a._value = a.string.replace('"', '\\"')
                _root = DefTree().get_root()
                attr = _root.add_attribute("data", "")
                parent = x.get_parent()
                index = parent.index(x)
                parent.remove(x)
                parent.insert(index, attr)
                x._parent = None
                text = cls.serialize(x, True)
                _root.set_attribute("data", '"{}"'.format(text.replace('\"', '\\\"').replace('\n', "\\\n")))
                del data_elements[max(data_elements)]

        return '"{}"'.format(cls.serialize(ele).replace("\n", '\\n\"\n  \"'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't say that's unreadable ! But there's some room for improvement, mostly style I think. Here's what I came up with, in no particular order:

#### Leading underscores in names

Leading underscores are supposed to be used to indicate that the object is "private", although that has no real meaning in Python: it's just a convention that says "beware if you use this, it might change its name or its implementation and is not part of the public API".

-> You should remove them at least for method argument; they don't add any meaning here and that does not help readability.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

#### Recursion with nonlocal variables

In `construct_string`, you use variables from outside the function's scope for recursion purposes. I would advise against this, it's not very Pythonic, and it's generally better to avoid side effects that make the code harder to understand.

-> Just pass them as arguments to the recursive calls.

#### Class/instance attribute confusion

In `BaseDefParser`, you declare `file_path` as a class attribute and manipulate it like an instance attribute in your methods. That can cause a lot of confusion especially with mutable objects as changes will be reflected upon all instances of the class.

-> Declare instance attributes in `__init__`.

#### `_raise_parse_error`

Having factorized this is a good idea, but you lost something on the way: you don't pass any context to this method that could help understand where the error is (except the document, but that's too broad).

-> Add context to your exceptions, you (or your future users and contributors) will thank yourself later for it !

#### Complexity

Your code is sparsely commented and not really easy to understand, you could sprinkle some comments there and there.

You could also split some of the more complex sections into smaller methods.

---

I'll update if I think of something else but that should be a good starting point. Anyway your code is pretty good, keep up if you're self taught !